# Cordova - plugin Admob free show Test Ads only

Tags: javascript, cordova, admob, cordova-plugins, cordova-admob

I developed a small application with Cordova. I added advertising through the free Admob plugin. The app has been published on the play store for over a month but the ads (banner, interstitials and rewards) are still in Test Ads mode.

How can I replace test ads by real ads?

I have a Google developer account and I created 3 ad units through Google Ad Mob, I also created a mediation group for each ad unit.

Cordova is in version 10

Here is the example code for the banner:

```
admob.banner.prepare();
admob.banner.show({
    id:'MY-ID',
    isTesting: false,
    autoShow:true
});
```

Everything is displayed well but in Ads test, on the emulator I understand but on the production version, I do not know how ...

[Preview Test Ads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqxJG.png)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I can not comment for the low reputation so I write it here: the id of the ad unit are you sure you have entered the correct one of the ad unit you created on admob and you have not made a mistake by entering a test id among those provided by google?
(I have sometimes created ad units but got confused with the codes)

Anyway, if you can't solve it, I advise you to post your question also in this official google group (they always answer): [Google Mobile Ads SDK Developers](https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk)